# why can't I access .layer.borderWidth for this UITextView instance? (code attached)

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextview, layer

why can't I access .layer.borderWidth for this UITextView instance?  (code attached)

```
UITextView *v = (UITextView*)[self.view viewWithTag:1];
v.layer.borderWidth = 1;  // ERROR Accessing unknown 'borderWidth' component of a property
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`.